# Could not resolve hostname http: Name or service not known

Tags: git

So i am trying to push my laravel project from my local machine to my digital ocean server.

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname http: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I actually am not using ssh to login to my server but password. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `ssh` and `http` in the error message suggest you have wrong remote URL syntax. Please show `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your git remote -v URL: it should be an ssh one, without any https in it.

Typically (as in "[DigitalOcean: Pushing changes to a remote server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-effectively#pushing-changes-to-a-remote-server)"):

```
git@git.droplet.com:my-project.git
ssh://git@git.domain.tld/repository.git
```

Once you have the correct remote URL, change the current one with:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@git.domain.tld/repository.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is delete your "Credential Record" for github account from Credential Manager.
I tried this and it worked for me.